# php curl download page after certain time

Tags: php, curl

I am using below function to download a webpage using curl function it works great.

Currently I am downloading a page from a site. Problem is that they are using 
a java script that have countdown of 15 sec. So is it possible to download 
this page after certain time (searched and brainstorm nothing work for me)?

```
function curldll($target_url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0)');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
    $html= curl_exec($ch);
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: You want to download page like it shows in a browser? Curl don't execute javascript. You can't do it with curl. You may download page via a browser.

Comment: You have to read that js, understand what it done, and reproduce its result using your php code. For example that JS set cookie: can-download=1, then your curl should send a cookie can-download=1. Depend on each website, you need to do this manually.

Answer (score 2):

Since page is using javascript timer to load content so you will not be able to do it by curl you can try [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), which is a headless WebKit browser which will execute the page fully and return the dynamically assembled DOM.

Comment: you can still use curl, it's just more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Try `HtmlUnit` library (Java), it's a fundament to `Selenium` and other apps who works with real browser. `cURL` can't work with `JavaScript`. Or use `PhantomJS`, if you like it more than `HtmlUnit`.